# Assembly how to translate JNE to C Code without ZF flag access

Tags: c, assembly, x86, machine-code, code-translation

ASM to C Code emulating nearly done.. just trying to solve these second pass problems.

Lets say I got this ASM function

```
401040  MOV EAX,DWORD PTR [ESP+8]
401044  MOV EDX,DWORD PTR [ESP+4]
401048  PUSH ESI
401049  MOV ESI,ECX
40104B  MOV ECX,EAX
40104D  DEC EAX
40104E  TEST ECX,ECX
401050  JE 401083
401052  PUSH EBX
401053  PUSH EDI
401054  LEA EDI,[EAX+1]
401057  MOV AX,WORD PTR [ESI]
40105A  XOR EBX,EBX
40105C  MOV BL,BYTE PTR [EDX]
40105E  MOV ECX,EAX
401060  AND ECX,FFFF
401066  SHR ECX,8
401069  XOR ECX,EBX
40106B  XOR EBX,EBX
40106D  MOV BH,AL
40106F  MOV AX,WORD PTR [ECX*2+45F81C]
401077  XOR AX,BX
40107A  INC EDX
40107B  DEC EDI
40107C  MOV WORD PTR [ESI],AX
40107F  JNE 401057
401081  POP EDI
401082  POP EBX
401083  POP ESI
401084  RET 8
```

My program would create the following for it.

```
int Func_401040() {
    regs.d.eax = *(unsigned int *)(regs.d.esp+0x00000008);
    regs.d.edx = *(unsigned int *)(regs.d.esp+0x00000004);
    regs.d.esp -= 4;
    *(unsigned int *)(regs.d.esp) = regs.d.esi;
    regs.d.esi = regs.d.ecx;
    regs.d.ecx = regs.d.eax;
    regs.d.eax--;
    if(regs.d.ecx == 0)
        goto label_401083;
    regs.d.esp -= 4;
    *(unsigned int *)(regs.d.esp) = regs.d.ebx;
    regs.d.esp -= 4;
    *(unsigned int *)(regs.d.esp) = regs.d.edi;
    regs.d.edi = (regs.d.eax+0x00000001);
    regs.x.ax = *(unsigned short *)(regs.d.esi);
    regs.d.ebx ^= regs.d.ebx;
    regs.h.bl = *(unsigned char *)(regs.d.edx);
    regs.d.ecx = regs.d.eax;
    regs.d.ecx &= 0x0000FFFF;
    regs.d.ecx >>= 0x00000008;
    regs.d.ecx ^= regs.d.ebx;
    regs.d.ebx ^= regs.d.ebx;
    regs.h.bh = regs.h.al;
    regs.x.ax = *(unsigned short *)(regs.d.ecx*0x00000002+0x0045F81C);
    regs.x.ax ^= regs.x.bx;
    regs.d.edx++;
    regs.d.edi--;
    *(unsigned short *)(regs.d.esi) = regs.x.ax;
    JNE 401057
    regs.d.edi = *(unsigned int *)(regs.d.esp);
    regs.d.esp += 4;
    regs.d.ebx = *(unsigned int *)(regs.d.esp);
    regs.d.esp += 4;
    label_401083:
    regs.d.esi = *(unsigned int *)(regs.d.esp);
    regs.d.esp += 4;
    return 0x8;
}
```

Since `JNE 401057` doesn't use the `CMP` or `TEST`

How do I fix that use this in C code?

Comment: If you're writing an emulator, you're going to have to emulate the flags register, too. And depending on how sneaky the code is, you may have to emulate jumping into the middle of an instruction.

Comment: As a matter a fact I have code that jumps improperly only 2 bytes.. so it goes into a previous instruction.. and renders it completely differently. `jp short near ptr loc_41FA2B+2` (I posted this in another question) got it resolved by manual hand patching. But the output. I'm trying to generate is similar to another output of some unknown emulator which didn't use flags and still functioned perfectly!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most recent instruction that modified flags is the `dec`, which sets ZF when its operand hits 0.  So the `jne` is about equivalent to `if (regs.d.edi != 0) goto label_401057;`.

BTW: `ret 8` isn't equivalent to `return 8`.  The `ret` instruction's operand is the number of bytes to add to ESP when returning.  (It's commonly used to clean up the stack.)  It'd be kinda like

```
return eax;
regs.d.esp += 8;
```

except that semi-obviously, this won't work in C -- the `return` makes any code after it unreachable.

This is actually a part of the calling convention -- `[ESP+4]` and `[ESP+8]` are arguments passed to the function, and the `ret` is cleaning those up.  This isn't the usual C calling convention; it looks more like fastcall or thiscall, considering the function expects a value in ECX.

Comment: So you are saying when I popped out 4 bytes aka ESI. I need to pop out another 8 bytes? 2 more 32-bit values which are not part of the registers? I always thought when a `CALL` occurs a new stack is kinda created, I guess the esp +8; is for the parameters? to be popped out? It's fine.. I dont even need that return 0x8; I plan to rewrite the subroutine part with `void Func_addr() { ... }` the way it performs is much more important to me. How about regular `RET`? do I need to add anything to ESP for that, well it is also aliased as `RET 0` so 0 after all right? so nothing to do with RET?

Comment: @SSpoke: The `ret` pops those 8 bytes for you.  They were arguments to the function -- the caller was like `push arg2 / push arg1 / call 0x401040`.  They have to be cleaned up by either the caller or the callee.  In this case the callee is cleaning them up.  If you're rewriting both the caller and callee, though, you can use your compiler's calling convention and don't need to worry about the stack -- the compiler will take care of it for you.

Comment: @SSpoke: and `ret 0` works the same as `ret` -- it pops the return address into EIP, and that's it.

Comment: Wait a second, you said The ret pops those 8 bytes for you? you meant `ret 8`? not regular ret right? If that is the case I understand this logic fully now.. so caller method would be `push 0 / push 1 / call 0x401040 (this being ret/ret 0) / add esp, 8 //(clear pushes 0,1 which happens outside the function call)` Well yeah I don't need to worry about return addresses, I believe, yeah that should do it.

Comment: @SSpoke: Yeah...the `ret 8` pops the extra 8 bytes.  Plain `ret` (with no operand) doesn't pop anything but the return address -- `ret 8` would pop the return address, then bump ESP by 8 more.  It's not part of the meat of the function either way, though; it's just calling-convention stuff.  If you're just reimplementing the functionality, you don't need to worry about it other than noting the calling convention if you need to remain compatible with the old code.